# Laravel 5.5: How to get top selling items of a given shop?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

My tables are like:

**shops**
`[id]`

**inventories**
`[id, shop_id]`

**orders**
`[id, shop_id]`

**order_item**
`[order_id, inventory_id, quantity]`

Models:

```
//Shop
class Shop extends Model
{
    public function inventories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Inventory::class);
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}

//Inventory
class Inventory extends Model
{
    public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Shop::class);
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'order_items')
                    ->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}

//Order
class Order extends Model
{
    public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Shop::class);
    }

    public function inventories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Inventory::class, 'order_items')
                    ->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}
```

Now I want 5 top selling inventories of a given shop, What will be the best possible way to do that?

I'm on Laravel 5.5

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Didn't able to find anything useful! :(

Comment: If you have models for each migration you can say something like in order model use shop model and say `$this->hasMany('App\order', 'id');` And so on for each

Comment: I've edited the question, I guess now it's clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this was my own question I found the solution on my own and I want to share the solution with the community. I wanted to solve it using Eloquent because I need the model on the view and didn't want to query the model again.

```
    Inventory::where('shop_id', \Auth::user()->shop_id)
                    ->select(
                        'inventories.*',
                        \DB::raw('SUM(order_items.quantity) as quantity')
                    )
                    ->join('order_items', 'inventories.id', 'order_items.inventory_id')
                    ->groupBy('inventory_id')
                    ->get();
```

I hope this'll help someone with similar issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.id,sum(oi.quantity) as total from munna.shops as s
join munna.inventories as iv on s.id=iv.shop_id
join munna.orders as o on iv.shop_id=o.shop_id
join munna.order_items as oi on o.id=oi.order_id
group by s.id
order by total desc limit 5
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something using the Eloquent?

Comment: I do not think eloquent will handle this complex query. Although if so then it would be costly.  Use DB::select()

Answer (score 1):

First, by looking at your tables on **order_item**, ***the order_id and inventory_id*** will bellong to the same shop for sure? I guess yes because if not you would have 2 different shops with same top order. I dont know why you are doing it like this but it's a bit confusing can't figure out why but I would try this:

```
public function topOrders()
{
    $items = DB::table('shops')
                  ->join('orders', 'shops.id', '=', 'orders.shop_id')
                  ->join('inventories', 'shops.id', '=', 'inventories.shop_id')
                  ->join('order_items', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_items.order_id')
                  ->orderBy('quantity', 'desc')
                  ->take(5)
                  ->get();
    return $items;
}
```

What I wrote should select everything from all 3 rows, if you want to select only the items or whatever you want to select you can specify it adding a select clause

Comment: You are about to post something or you mean you used my asnwer?